# Need help on Arduino as ISP

Tags: arduino-uno

If I use an Arduino board to bootload a new chip, is it still possible to use the microcontroller on the board for another project, or it will only be for bootloading new chips.

Answer (score 2):

There are more ways to flash a bootloader to new AVR chip. To which you refer? If you replace the chip on Uno to burn a bootloader to it with a programmer, then it is very unclear what you are asking, because the original chip is not involved in this process.

If you ask about ArduinoISP sketch, then simply it is a sketch. You upload it as any other sketch and replace it with any other sketch.